# Viber chat run multiple instances

Tags: windows-7, multiple-instances, viber

I have two mobile phone numbers so that I want to have two instances of Viber desktop application on the same PC running Windows 7.

I want to chat with my friends from two viber account at the same time.

How can I do that?

Comment: @Lưu has said the devs have said no but one thing I would try is setting up another user on your PC and run as... the other user to see if it will allow 2 sessions if there under different users (There are many single instance application that will allow 2 instances if they are under different users)

Comment: I'll try installing it as another user. Thanks for the idea

Comment: I've checked and that doesn't work :)

Comment: Only other solution I can suggest will mean a loss of notifications, virtualization of a windows instance.

Comment: @NamGVU I have a solution if you are still need one. Watch my answer.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create "NEW" windows account
2. Download vibersetup.exe
3. Run vibersetup.exe as "NEW" account
4. Start new installed viber as "NEW" account from C:\Users\"NEW"\AppData\Local\Viber\
5. Register as second phone number

Enjoy

Comment: How does this let the OP use both accounts ***at the same time***? Yes, I know: use `Run As`. This was suggested in a comment almost a year ago; the OP reported that it didn't work.

Comment: This is actually working when only one of the users is logged in. 

I've even created a shortcut using runas command: `C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:<second_username> "C:\Users\<second_username>\AppData\Local\Viber\Viber.exe"` 
which saves the credentials of the second user after the first execution. Then I put the shortcut in the startup folder. Now I have a PC with two instances of Viber running automatically on startup.

Answer (score 2):

No way. Currently you can have only one mobile device and one PC for one viber account

> Yes, you can! But only if one of the devices is your computer (PC or Mac). Viber Media Inc. launched Viber desktop version in May 2013

http://www.viberfaq.com/can-i-have-same-viber-account-on-two-different-devices/

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10 you can run the traditional 'Desktop' app and the universal 'Windows 10' app simultaneously. Both can be downloaded from the Viber website: [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAIXG.png).
I've just tried and managed to activate both using different Viber accounts. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh this indeed works for Windows 10!

Comment: This no longer works, as Viber is now not available for desktop devices in Windows Store.

Answer (score 2):

I tried Sandboxie and it really helped me:

http://take.ms/N4GBI

If you are already authentificated in Viber at PC, then:

1. logout in Viber at PC
2. launch Viber at Sandboxie (can run with `%LocalAppData%\Viber\Viber.exe`), authentificate
3. launch Viber in regular way, authentificate

Comment: You can also go to "your_sandbox_name\user\current\AppData\Roaming\ViberPC\config.db" and REWRITE the file (open with notepad and delete all the contents). Do not delete the file, it will be created again from the same file outside of your sandbox

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run several `Viber` instances (and actually, any app, that is supposed to be run in single instance) in one user session.

1. Create new local user, say `test` (**with** password)
2. Log in to `test`, so that Windows can create files for that user
3. After Windows finished preparations, switch back to your primary user
4. [Download](https://www.viber.com/en/download/) `vibersetup.exe` and move it to `C:\Users\test\Downloads`
5. `Shift` + `right click` on `C:\Users\test\Downloads\vibersetup.exe`, and select `Run as different user`. Select `test` user, enter password, install viber
6. Next time you want to start already installed viber: `Shift` + `right click` on `C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Viber\Viber.exe` -> `run as different user`

Note that, creating user with password, requires adding answers on questions.
If you want to avoid that, add user without passowrd, than change passowd via control panel.

### How to add it to start menu and run it w/o entering passowrd (optional)

1. `Right click` on `C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Viber\Viber.exe` -> `Create shortcut`
2. Move `Viber.exe - Shortcut` to `C:\Users\<your primary user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`
3. Rename `Viber.exe - Shortcut` to `Viber.exe - test`
4. `Right click` on `Viber.exe - test` -> `properties` -> `Shortcut`, then set `target` to `C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:test /savecred "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Viber\Viber.exe"`
5. Observe `Viber.exe - test` in the start menu!

Answer (score 0):

I recently used below method on both windows 10 and 11:

1. Create Local Account on Windows, and login with that account.
2. Now Download and install viber.
3. Sync the viber with your Phone (So that the viber on your PC can be opened).
4. Once the viber Opened, you can now Sign-out from that account.
5. Go back to your Main Account (the one that you want to run Multiple viber).
6. Right Click on Desktop and Create Shortcut
7. Paste the following (Change username only):

   C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:username "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Viber\Viber.exe"
8. Done!

Source: https://standingtech.com/randomarticles/run-multiple-viber-on-windows/